# Is there a word to describe "being formal for the sake of being formal"?

Tags: word-choice

I was recently chastised at work for using the word "*cool*" in an email chain--an act that I attribute to *being overly-formal for no other reason than to uphold an unnecessarily perceived "law" of formality.* Is there an English word that would better describe this?

Comment: This question probably belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) because it is about communication in everyday English, and is not about the academic study of English Language.

Comment: What?! *Cool* is slang not formal...

Comment: @Jim I think the OP attributes his chastisement to overdone formality.

Comment: I take it you mean 'slang not informal', Jim. And without more background, one cannot comment on whether 'work' or Noob is being unreasonable here. I remember that pupils at the school where I taught were always challenging the dress code as being overfastidious, but it helped maintain overall standards.

Comment: @AndrewLeach- Oh I see. When I first read it it seemed he was saying that his act of using the word "cool" was overly formal... Duh...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The apt words are

***Prig***

> a person who displays or demands of others pointlessly precise conformity, fussiness about trivialities, or exaggerated propriety, especially in a self-righteous or irritating manner.

***Prude***

> a person who is excessively proper or modest in speech, conduct, dress, etc.

***Pedant***

> a person who overemphasizes rules or minor details.
>
> a person who adheres rigidly to book knowledge without regard to common sense.

Comment: Hmm "don't use a smiley in a business email" "ahh don't be a prig!" - maybe no?

Comment: `Pedant`, eh? Looks like we have a winner! Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

[Stuffy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stuffy) comes to mind -

> Rigidly adhering to standards of conduct; strait-laced
>   excessively dull, staid, or conventional

Comment: +1 Anal comes to mind as well ;-)

Comment: Yeah, but that is a bit OTT: anal retentive - a stage in psychosexual development when the child's interest is concentrated on the anal region; fixation at this stage is said to result in orderliness, meanness, stubbornness, compulsiveness, etc.

Comment: +1 as many of the alternatives are (more) insulting, at least in some contexts.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps *[prissy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prissy)* would suit your meaning:-

> Excessively or affectedly prim and proper.

Comment: The people I have met I would call prissy, MIGHT also be stuffy, but not necessarily. Prissy to me is more prudish and "Ohhh do not let your dirty dog mess up my white dress"

Answer (score 3):

You might consider **[pompous](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/pompous)**

> someone who is pompous thinks they are very important and speaks or behaves in a very serious and formal way

The term also carries with it the connotation of *self-important* that may or may not fit your circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

"Formalist" could do ?

check definition here:

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/formalist
http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/formalist

For more negative emphasis:
"pedant"

maybe could also do.