# What does “over-formal” means?

Tags: meaning

> An ideal article should have the following:
>   • Appropriate and Correct
>   English Professional, but not over-formal, U.S. English.

Comment: Excessively formal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over-formal seems to mean "overly formal" or "too formal", from the context you provided. Meaning that being too formal is best avoided as well, formality needs to be adjusted to the situation.

I'm not sure if over-formal is correct English, I can't seem to find any occurrences of this.

If you're interested in synonyms that can be used, [this question already covered that.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125398/is-there-a-word-to-describe-being-formal-for-the-sake-of-being-formal)

Comment: It would need to be *overly formal*. But as *overly* doesn't sound like a proper word to me, I would use *excessively formal*.